# Permission for wsdl2apex class

Tags: apex

I have a class generated from wsdl . How do I decide which profiles get access to the class. (How do I determine the access criteria , since there is no object involved . Otherwise I could have checked which profile has access to those objects used in the class) .Will it be only integration user?

Answer (score 0):

Usually access rights would not be thought about per class, but rather at a higher level. So you probably don't need to do anything.

An example of a "higher level" is a Visualforce page or REST endpoint. Access rights to those can be granted via profiles to e.g. only the integration user.

But if you really want to guard calls to this class from other contexts - e.g. asynchronous Apex kicked off from a trigger - you can use the methods of [UserInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm) to find out about the current user and add whatever conditional logic you like in Apex code.

Comment: Thanks Keith . My current concern is running the test classes as business user . As of now I was testing as Sys admin . By looking at the WSDL2APEX class , is there a way to determine which all profiles can be potential users?

Comment: @Vanilla_Sky For tests you will need to write and add a WebServiceMock or use Test.isRunningTest() to avoid the call. I really don't understand why you want to add profile/user specific logic to the generated class and I suggest you should not.